# Providing Word style table editing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, html-table

I want to edit a HTML table in a similar style to how Word edits tables.

I have found lots and lots of extensions and plugins which turn tables into something akin to excel where a cell is selected and then "activating" it edits it (e.g. datatables, handsontable, jqgrid etc). However what I'm after is something more like Microsoft Word's table editing. Essentially each cell can contain multiple paragraphs, you are always editing the cell, and when you use the arrow keys and get to the end of one cell it takes you to the start of the next.

contentEditable is OK, but then you can't really do cell selections like Word does as it just selects to the edge of the page (at least in Chrome). I thought something like this would already exist, but I haven't been able to find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: So something that seems "close" is if each cell is contenteditable, however it then raises a new question: how can I detect that I'm on the first line when they press the up arrow to move the focus?

Comment: Duh. The y value of the caret won't change.